# I sometimes add code to insert a breakpoint. Is there another way? If not, what's the best solution?

Tags: c#, breakpoints

This is a silly thing I catch myself doing once in a while and I feel that it is a bad habit. It usually goes like this:

1. I try to place a breakpoint but cannot because there is not a valid stopping point for the processor.
2. So I insert a silly code to break on and then delete later. (unless it gets forgotten D:)

For example, let's say I want to pause inside an empty constructor like this one:

```
public ImAConstructor()
{
    //I want to break here but can't :(
}
```

So I do something like this instead:

```
public ImAConstructor()
{
    int testVar = 0; //TODO: Delete this code. Temporarily inserted to break on.
}
```

Which just feels ugly to type and probably upsets the programming gods.

I would like a way to do this that doesn't risk leaving pointless code that could confuse others.

Comment: Seems like you should add the tag for the IDE you're using.

Comment: You can break on the start of the constructor, even an empty one...

Comment: You should be able to set a breakpoint on the line with the opening curly brace.

Comment: in Visual Studio you can break on a brace `{`.  So breaking in an empty ctor wouldnt be a problem.

Comment: You can use the end curly brace too

Comment: Generally however, no, you do not want to put in code that does nothing just to create a break point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using VisualStudio to develop your application, you should be able to place a breakpoint on the opening `{` and the closing `}` bracket.

Comment: Does  this also work on 'Release' mode, because they could be optimized 'away'?

Comment: @Silvermind - Interestingly this also works in the "Release mode", though only the closing bracket `}` is respected, the opening bracket will be ignored (VS 2010). Anyway, setting breakpoints is surely more important in the "Debug mode".